# Why is PySpin not detecting any cameras even though the FLIR camera is connected to my mac?

Tags: flir, pyspin

I have a MacBook Pro 16' from 2019 and I've been trying to configure PySpin to work, but whenever I run the default DeviceEvents.py file, it is unable to detect any cameras. This is what it outputs:

```
Library version: 3.1.0.79
Number of cameras detected: 0
Not enough cameras!
```

Everything else works perfectly as far as I'm aware, and when I check my Mac's system information, the camera appears to be connected to a USB-C port.

I have already tried reconnecting the camera to every port on my mac, restarting my mac, and I'm not sure what else to do. I've tried configuring the DeviceEvents.py file but I also saw no results there. The camera is still not being detected after all that.